# How to use Internet Banking for Brazilian Banco do Santander in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox

*In English:*

An Internet Banking protection module for Brazilian Banco do Santander only has a Windows version. Does anyone know any official alternative module to use in Ubuntu? I've already sent an email to the bank and they never responded.

It is a Firefox dedicated plug-in: https://wwws2.santandernet.com.br/MPS/bin/gbplugin2.exe

In https://www.santandernet.com.br/IBPF/transacoes/mps/mps_problemas.asp informs that exists a java version, but I can't find this.

Hello Linux community in Brazil, we put pressure on Santander to release a version of the security module in Ubuntu at least.

*Brazilian:*

O Módulo de proteção do Internet Banking do santander só existe na versão do windows. Alguém conhece alguma alternativa oficial do Santander para utilizar no Ubuntu? Já mandei e-mail para eles e eles nunca responderam.

Ele é um plug-in dedicado do Firefox (ver link acima)

Em (ver link acima) informa que existe uma versão java, mas eu não pude encontrá-lo.

Alô comunidade Linux no Brasil, vamos fazer pressão no Santander para liberar uma versão do módulo de segurança no Ubuntu pelo menos.

Comment: Uhm, shouldn't the questions here be in English?

Comment: Already translated.  Waiting for peer review...  Give him a break: he's a newbie!  ;-)

Comment: Do you have any info or reference? How does the security module work? Is it a stand-alone application? A dedicated browser plug-in? An applet for a common plug-in like Java or Flash? Unfortunately I understand Portuguese nowhere near enough and http://www.santander.com.br/ doesn't seem to offer an English translation. P.S.: We have similar issues with the NFC-based (online) authentication function of the new government-issued ID cards in Germany.

Comment: Sorry! My future posts, I will add a translated version. Thanks Fabby for this translation

Comment: @DavidFoerster is a Firefox dedicated plug-in: [https://wwws2.santandernet.com.br/MPS/bin/gbplugin2.exe](https://wwws2.santandernet.com.br/MPS/bin/gbplugin2.exe) 

In [https://www.santandernet.com.br/IBPF/transacoes/mps/mps_problemas.asp](https://www.santandernet.com.br/IBPF/transacoes/mps/mps_problemas.asp) informs that exists a java version, but I can't find this.

Comment: @ViniciusSousa: Thanks for the info. You should [edit] your question to include it, so all the relevant stuff is in one place instead of scattered throughout the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the protection module was developed for Windows only. The solution (for now) is to install [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), then Mozilla Firefox for Windows (on Wine) and, finally, install the internet banking protection module provided by Santander Brazil.

Brazillian

Infelizmente parece que o módulo de proteção foi desenvolvido apenas para Windows. A solução (por enquanto) é instalar o [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), depois o Mozilla Ferifox para Windows (no Wine) e, finalmente, instalar o módulo de proteção do internet banking fornecido pelo Santander Brasil.

Comment: Thanks. Now informs that the protection module is installed.
----------------------------------------------------
Obrigado, Agora informa que o modulo de proteção está instalado.